# Prove that a function is alpha convex

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, convex-analysis

I consider a functional $J$ defined on $W^{1,2}(0,1)$ by

$$
J(v) =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\lvert v’\rvert^{2} + \lvert v\rvert^{2} - \int_{0}^{1}fv\quad f\in L^{2}(0,1)
$$

I want to prove that $J$ is $\alpha$ convex that is

$$
J(\frac{v+u}{2})\leq \frac{J(v)+J(u)}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{8}\lVert v - u\rVert^{2}
$$

Where $\alpha>0$ and $v’$ is the weak derivative of $v$.

My attempt : first we see that, using $\lVert . \rVert$ to denote the norm induced by the scalar product, that

$$
J(v) = \frac{1}{2}\lVert v’\rVert^{2} + \frac{1}{2}\lVert v\rVert^{2} - \langle f,v\rangle
$$

Now using the parallelogram identity we see that

$$
J(\frac{v+u}{2}) =\frac{1}{2}\left(\lVert \frac{v + u}{2} \rVert^{2} + \lVert \frac{v’ + u’}{2} \rVert^{2}\right)- \frac{1}{2}\langle f,v+u\rangle = \frac{1}{8} \left(2\lVert v\rVert^{2} + 2\lVert u\rVert^{2} - \lVert v - u\rVert^{2} + 2\lVert v’\rVert^{2} + 2\lVert u’\rVert^{2} - \lVert v’ - u’\rVert^{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\langle f, v\rangle + \langle f, u \rangle\right)
$$

This gives

$$
J(\frac{v+u}{2}) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\lVert v\rVert^{2} +\lVert v’\rVert^{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\langle f, v\rangle +  \frac{1}{4}\left(\lVert u\rVert^{2} +\lVert u’\rVert^{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\langle f, u\rangle - \frac{1}{8}\lVert v-u\rVert^{2} - \frac{1}{8}\lVert v’-u’\rVert^{2} =  \frac{J(v) + J(u)}{2} - \frac{1}{8}\lVert v - u\rVert^{2} - \frac{1}{8}\lVert v’-u’\rVert^{2}\leq \frac{J(v) + J(u)}{2} - \frac{1}{8}\lVert v - u\rVert^{2}
$$

And we see that $\alpha = 1$.

Is this seems correct please ?

Comment: There is something wrong with the second equation above, if $f=0$ and $u \neq v$ then  the right hand side is negative and the left hand side is positive.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for the remark, indeed it is $J$ that must appears in the definition of the $\alpha$ convexity (in the right hand side) not $f$. It was a mistake. Also there was a big mistake that made me revise the proof. Do not hesitate to comment it if something seems wrong !

Comment: I added an answer below. I think you are complicating things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making life difficult for yourself.

By $\| \cdot \|$ below I mean the Sobolev norm on $W^{1,2}(0,1)$.

It is straightforward to see that if $g$ is $\alpha$ convex and $h$ is convex, then $g+h$ is $\alpha$ convex.

If $g$ is $\alpha$ convex and $\beta>0$ then $\beta g$ is $\alpha \beta $ convex.

In any Hilbert space, the norm squared $v \mapsto \| v \|^2$ is $2$ convex. This is straightforward to establish using the basic properties of the inner product.

Hence $g(v) = {1 \over 2} \|v\|^2$ is $1$ convex, and since $h(v) = -\langle f, v \rangle $ is linear (and hence convex) we see that
$J(v) = g(v)+h(v)$ is $1$ convex.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very clear. You’re right using the Sobolev norm directly is more appropriate !